# UICollectionView: how to load more cells than the screen size using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I working with a UICollectionView and with custom collectionViewCells and I know exactly how dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier works. When a cell disappear from the screen (after a scroll), this same cell is used to display the new one. But, because my cells take time to display, it doesn't really looks good if I scroll to fast.

This is an example of how it works :

[image]

What I want is cell 4 (and 5 and 6) to be loaded even if it's not displayed on the screen. So, I would like to use a "buffer" in which the next 3 cells will be loaded. And if I scroll down a little bit and cell 1 disappear, cell 1 is used to load cell 7. Is that possible?

Thank you !

Comment: Please don't tag Swift related questions with the objective-c tag

Comment: Actually it's not related to Swift either, it's an iOS framework question...

Answer (score 0):

Why cells are not ready? Perhaps are you loading images from web?
You can try those options:

1 - try to use the willDisplayCell to dequeue one or more cell and load there in some cache (for example a simple array), after in cellForItemAtIndexPath load directly from cache...

2 - you have to rewrite a recycle scrollview...there are some example from Apple on wwdc 2011 or 2012 about it and surely you can find some example...in this way you can decide how many cells are loaded those recycled.

Comment: Yes I'm loading pictures from a Database using Parse... I ll try those options and let you know